# Extending appengine's db.Property with caching

Tags: python, google-app-engine, descriptor

I'm looking to implement a property class for appengine, very similar to the existing `db.ReferenceProperty`. I am implementing my own version because I want some other default return values. My question is, how do I make the property remember its returned value, so that the datastore query is only performed the first time the property is fetched? What I had is below, and it does not work. I read that the Property classes do not belong to the instances, but to the model definition, so I guess that the return value is not cached for each instance, but overwritten on the model every time. Where *should* I store this `_resolved` variable?

```
class PageProperty(db.Property):
  data_type = Page

  def get_value_for_datastore(self, model_instance):
    page = super(PageProperty, self).get_value_for_datastore(model_instance)        
    self._resolved = page
    return page.key().name()

  def make_value_from_datastore(self, value):
    if not hasattr(self, '_resolved'):
        self._resolved = Page.get_by_name(value)
    return self._resolved
```

#### Edit

Alex' answer is certainly usable. But it seems that the built-in `db.ReferenceProperty` *does* store the `_RESOLVED` variable on the model instance. As evidenced by:

```
[...]
    setattr(model_instance, self.__resolved_attr_name(), value)
[...]

def __resolved_attr_name(self):
    return '_RESOLVED' + self._attr_name()
```

The `get_value_for_datastore` method is passed the model instance, but `make_value_from_datastore` is not, so how do they find the `_RESOLVED` property from that method?

#### Edit 2

From the [code](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/source/browse/trunk/python/google/appengine/ext/db/__init__.py#2819) I gather that google is using the `__get__()` and `__set__()` methods, both of which do get the model instance as an argument. Are those usable in custom classes? What is the difference with `get_value_for_datastore` and its counterpart?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want to change some small part of the behaviour of ReferenceProperty, you may want to simply extend it, overriding its [default_value](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/propertyclass.html#Property_default_value) method. You may find [the source](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/source/browse/trunk/python/google/appengine/ext/db/__init__.py#2819) for ReferenceProperty to be instructive.

Comment: I want it to return a new entity of its kind when the stored key is not found. That, and some other things.  

Regarding the source. I don't understand how the `ReferenceProperty` is storing the `_RESOLVED` entity _on the model instance_, and not, like Alex explained, in a dict on the property instance.

Comment: It uses getattr/setattr on the passed in model instance to set/retrieve the _resolved property. You should be able to implement the behaviour you want by subclassing ReferenceProperty, overriding __get__, and having it catch db.Error. If an error is raised, create a new instance, call __set__, and return the instance.

Answer (score 2):

A `PageProperty` instance exists per-model, not per-entity (where an entity is an instance of the model class).  So I think you need a *dictionary* that maps pagename -> Page entity, instead of a single attribute per PageProperty instance.  E.g., maybe something like...:

```
class PageProperty(db.Property):
  data_type = Page

  def __init__(self, *a, **k):
    super(PageProperty, self).__init__(*a, **k)
    self._mycache = {}       

  def get_value_for_datastore(self, model_instance):
    page = super(PageProperty, self).get_value_for_datastore(model_instance)        
    name = page.key().name()
    self._mycache[name] = page
    return name

  def make_value_from_datastore(self, value):
    if value not in self._mycache:
        self._mycache[value] = Page.get_by_name(value)
    return self._mycache[value]
```

Comment: I thought I had overlooked a way to access the entity from the `Property`.

Comment: No, the Property instance belongs to the whole model (that's why you set it as part of the class body!), not to each specific entity (instance of the model), that's the key point -- so there can't be a way to access a specific entity given only the instance of Property.

Comment: You don't need a dictionary - simply store the property values on the entity in question. This is the approach that the ReferenceProperty class takes (along with, in fact, every other property class). Keeping a dict will result in one of ever increasing size!